# 3 phase AC motor speed control using inverter drive

Tags: power, circuit-design

as per the subject i had taken a small project of re-modification of a production machine called (Flanging machine) especially used for the cutting and bending of buffle type sheet.

know the motor rating is 3 phase 380V 7.5KW star connected .
constant speed, 
know the re-modification to this motor is as follows;-
1) motor driven speed should be control
is it possible to reduce the speed driven by motor

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect the motor to a socalled VFD (Variable Frequency Device). Such a device can control the speed of the motor in a wide range.

From the power requirements a 3 phase version is needed. Therefore 380-400 VAC 3phase input. Then you have 3phase 380-400 VAC output. The obtained output is input frequency independant and can vary between 0 rpm ( external cooling required) and some 10 to 20% over the designspeed of the motor. Modern VFD's allow you to make a fully automated setup. However if the requirement become very specific manual setup might be needed.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response and i will try to make it this way.

Comment: If you are happy then upvote and accept